# How to pause and restart the Qtimer on QT

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qtimer

I have a Ubuntu , and i'am working with IDE `QT` on `C++` . 
I will to pause and resume the Qtimer , for exampe :

```
void Ordonnancer_les_taches::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    connect(&dataTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(l_odonnancement()));
    dataTimer.start(5000);
}
```

How to `Pause` and how `Restart` ? 
give me an exmple

Answer (score 12):

Since there is no dedicated method to achieve this behaviour, you could do something like this (you may move it to a subclass PausableTime or so):

```
void pause() {
    int remaining = dataTimer.remainingTime();
    dataTimer.stop();
    dataTimer.setInterval(remaining);
}

void resume() {
    dataTimer.start();
}
```

Of course you then need to adjust the interval in your timeout slot again.

Comment: @StackTok To pause, do as described in this answer. To stop call [`QTimer::stop`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#stop). To restart just call [`QTimer::start`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#start-1).

Comment: @StackTok What does that mean, increment two by two?

Comment: @thuga for exemple , i do : dataTimer.start(1000); . 
the system execute 1 -> 2 ->  3 >4 ...... step by step  . 
if i do stop and start : the system execute 
1 > 4 >  6 >  8>  ...

Comment: @StackTok What are these numbers `1->2->3->4`? Are they seconds elapsed?

Comment: @StackTok I think I see what is going on. You are incrementing some value in `l_odonnancement` slot. The problem is you are connecting the timer's `timeout` signal to that slot every time you click the button. Either connect it somewhere else *(like in the constructor of your class)* which is what I would do, or use [`Qt::UniqueConnection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Comment: @StackTok Docs state: [*By default, a signal is emitted for every connection you make; two signals are emitted for duplicate connections. You can break all of these connections with a single disconnect() call. If you pass the Qt::UniqueConnection type, the connection will only be made if it is not a duplicate. If there is already a duplicate (exact same signal to the exact same slot on the same objects), the connection will fail and connect will return an invalid QMetaObject::Connection.*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect)